# Object dosen't support this property or method document.getElementById().Value

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run a VBS but keep getting error.

Object dosen't support this property or method document.getElementById().Value
Try reset my IE setting to default and use other version of IE still facing the same problem

Below is the script details

```js
strAssets = "Assets.txt"
strOutput = "AssetWarranties.csv"
strSite = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const intForReading = 1
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strAssets, intForReading, False)
Set objOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutput, True)
objOutput.WriteLine """Serial"",""Status"",""Telephone Support"",""Expiry"",""Hardware Support"",""Expiry"""

While Not objInput.AtEndOfStream
 strImei = Trim(objInput.ReadLine)
 If strImei <> "" Then
  Set objFF = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  objFF.Visible = True
  objFF.Navigate strSite
  While objFF.ReadyState <> 4 Or objFF.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 100
  Wend
  objFF.document.getElementById("serialnumbercheck"). Value = strImei
  objFF.document.getElementById("warrantycheckbutton"). Click()
  While InStr(objFF.Document.body.InnerHTML, "<H3 id=registration-true>") = 0 And _
   InStr(objFF.Document.body.InnerHTML, "<H3 id=registration-false>") = 0 And _
   InStr(objFF.Document.body.InnerHTML, "serial number is not valid") = 0
   WScript.Sleep 100
  Wend
  
  strPageText = objFF.Document.body.InnerHTML
  objFF.Quit
  
  If InStr(strPageText, "serial number is not valid") > 0 Then
   'WScript.Echo "Serial number is not valid"
   objOutput.WriteLine """" & strImei & """,""Serial number is not valid"""
  Else
   strDetail = """" & strImei & """"
   If InStr(strPageText, "<H3 id=registration-true>") > 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo "Valid Purchase Date"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Valid Purchase Date"""
   Else
    'WScript.Echo "Purchase Date not Validated"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Purchase Date not Validated"""
   End If
   If InStr(strPageText, "<H3 id=phone-true>") > 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo "Telephone Technical Support: Active"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Telephone Technical Support: Active"""
    intPos = InStr(InStr(strPageText, "<H3 id=phone-true>"), strPageText, "Estimated Expiration Date: ")
    If intPos > 0 Then
     strExpiration = Mid(strPageText, intPos, InStr(intPos, strPageText, "</P>") - intPos)
     'WScript.Echo strExpiration
     strDetail = strDetail & ",""" & strExpiration & """"
    Else
     'WScript.Echo "Estimated Expiration Date: UNKNOWN"
     strDetail = strDetail & ",""Estimated Expiration Date: UNKNOWN"""
    End If
   Else
    'WScript.Echo "Telephone Technical Support: Expired"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Telephone Technical Support: Expired"""
   End If
   If InStr(strPageText, "<H3 id=hardware-true>") > 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo "Repairs and Service Coverage: Active"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Repairs and Service Coverage: Active"""
    intPos = InStr(InStr(strPageText, "<H3 id=hardware-true>"), strPageText, "Estimated Expiration Date: ")
    If intPos > 0 Then
     strExpiration = Mid(strPageText, intPos, InStr(intPos, strPageText, "<BR>") - intPos)
     'WScript.Echo strExpiration
     strDetail = strDetail & ",""" & strExpiration & """"
    Else
     'WScript.Echo "Estimated Expiration Date: UNKNOWN"
     strDetail = strDetail & ",""Estimated Expiration Date: UNKNOWN"""
    End If
   Else
    'WScript.Echo "Repairs and Service Coverage: Not Active"
    strDetail = strDetail & ",""Repairs and Service Coverage: Not Active"""
   End If
   objOutput.WriteLine strDetail
  End If
 End If
Wend
objInput.Close
objOutput.Close
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use >> objFF.document.getElementById("sn").value = strImei

insted of "objFF.document.getElementById("serialnumbercheck").Value = strImei"

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
objFF.document.getElementById("sn"). Value = strImei
```

because `serialnumbercheck` is the name of the `<form>`, not the input field